# Converting an Adjacency Matrix to an Adjacency List in C

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I am supposed to convert a given adjacency matrix to an adjacency list in C. I need this adjacency list because this is where I will implement my algorithm for Depth First Search (DFS). Before I write my code for DFS, I wanna make sure that I made the right adjacency list. However, my problem is that when I try to run my code, the program does not proceed in printing the graph. I believe it's because of how I read user inputs because that is exactly where the program stops. Now my question is, how do I read multiple inputs in one line? I tried using fgets() but my program does not proceed in printing the graph/adjacency list. Provided below is the code that I wrote.

Here are the struct nodes:

```
typedef struct vertexnode VertexNode;
struct vertexnode
{
    int vertex;
    VertexNode *Next;
};

typedef struct graph 
{
    int numVertices;
    VertexNode **adjLists;
} Graph;
```

Below is the main function:

```
int main()
{
    int size, i, temp;
    //char input1[100000];

    scanf("%d\n", &size);   // scan number of vertices
    Graph *graph = createAGraph(size);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)  // scan the adjacency MATRIX
    {
        char input1[100000];
        int j = 0;
        fgets(input1, sizeof(input1), stdin);
        char *piece = strtok(input1, " "); // extract first number
        while(piece != NULL)
        {
            temp = atoi(piece); // convert from char to int
            if(temp == 1)   // create new node
            {
                addEdge(graph, i, j); //add edge from vertex i to j
            }
            j++;
            piece = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }

    printGraph(graph);
    return 0;
}
```

Function for creating a vertex:

```
VertexNode *createVertex(int vertexNum)
{
    VertexNode *new_vertex = (VertexNode *) malloc(sizeof(VertexNode));
    new_vertex->vertex = vertexNum + 1;
    new_vertex->Next = NULL;
    return new_vertex;
}
```

Function for creating the graph:

```
Graph *createAGraph(int size)
{
    Graph *graph = (Graph *)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
    graph->numVertices = size;
    graph->adjLists = (VertexNode **)malloc(sizeof(VertexNode *));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        graph->adjLists[i] = NULL;
    return graph;
}
```

Function for addEdge:

```
void addEdge(Graph *graph, int s, int d)
{
    VertexNode *newNode = createVertex(d);
    newNode->Next = graph->adjLists[s];
    graph->adjLists[s] = newNode;
}
```

Function for printing the adjacency list:

```
void printGraph(Graph *graph)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < graph->numVertices; i++)
    {
        VertexNode *temp = graph->adjLists[i];
        printf("\n Vertex %d\n: ", i+1);
        while(temp)
        {
            printf("%d -> ", temp->vertex);
            temp = temp->Next;
        }
        newline;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of taking a user input given the context that we have to read multiple inputs in a line and there's an arbitrary number of lines?

Example Input:

```
4   
0 0 1 0  
1 0 0 1  
1 1 0 1  
0 1 0 0
```

**First input is the number of vertices in the list**
**The succeeding lines represent the adjacency matrix**

The adjacency list should be like this:

```
1 -> 3  
2 -> 1 -> 4  
3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4  
4 -> 2
```

Comment: *"my program runs into some errors*". And those errors would be what? Please update the question with the exact errors or incorrect behaviours.

Comment: Also, the code is incomplete. Questions asking for debugging help must provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: Beware that the loops are starting with 0, not 1 : so will be the edges of the graph.

Comment: @kaylum Hello. I already edited my post. :)

Comment: @JoëlHecht Yes. Under the function VertexNode *createVertex(int vertexNum), I add 1 to the vertex.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
    int i, j, size;
    char *tk;                           // pointer to a token
    char delim[] = " ";                 // delimiter of tokens
    char line[BUFSIZ];
    int *m;                             // matrix

    fgets(line, BUFSIZ, stdin);         // read stdin and assign line
    size = atoi(line);                  // size of matrix

    if (NULL == (m = malloc(sizeof(int) * size * size))) {
                                        // allocate a matrix
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (NULL == fgets(line, BUFSIZ, stdin)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "insufficient lines\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        j = 0;
        tk = strtok(line, delim);
        while (tk != NULL) {
            m[i * size + j] = atoi(tk); // assign element of matrix
            j++;
            if (j > size) {
                fprintf(stderr, "too many columns\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            tk = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        if (j < size) {
            fprintf(stderr, "insufficient columns\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // print the adjacency list
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (m[i * size + j]) {
                printf(" -> %d", j + 1);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As I'm not aware of your special functions such as `createAGraph()` or
`addEdge()`, I've used my own definition of matrix. Please modify
my code to meet your interfaces.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this. However, I will really need to make an adjacency list (not just print it) using **linked lists**. Because I need it in order to run Depth First Search (DFS). I already updated my post just in case you would like to help me. :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm sorry for misunderstanging about the list, but it will be quite easy to modify my code into the linked list if you're familiar with it. If you still have the problem, please let me know with the specific problem. I'm ready to write my own code using your functions but I'm not sure whether it will help you study the data structure. Good luck and best regards.